# Img-Slider how to add auto slide?

Tags: javascript

I have my img-slider, and I would like to add the possibility for images to scroll alone. What should I add?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // Initializing the swiper plugin for the slider.
    // Read more here: http://idangero.us/swiper/api/
    
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination' ,
            clickable: true
        },
        paginationClickable: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
        }
    });
    
});
```

idk how I have to try

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the slider script you are using? Your question isn't super clear, but when you say "*scroll alone*" if you mean scroll/play by itself there are [autoplay](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#autoplay) options.

Comment: thank you, you help me with the autoplay